# How to prefetch a @property with a Django queryset?

Tags: python, django, prefetch, django-select-related

I would like to prefetch a model property to a queryset in Django. Is there a way do that ?

Here are the three models:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    @property
    def bestpicurl(self):
        try:
            return self.placebestpic.picture.file.url
        except:
            return None

class PlaceBestPic(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place)
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Picture(models.Model):
    file = ImageField(max_length=500, upload_to="/images/")
```

I would need something like:

```
qs = Place.objects.all().select_related('bestpicurl')
```

Any clue how to do that ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) and [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) are instructions that are compiled into the database query/ies. Passing it the name of a pure Python property doesn't work because your database cannot know about them. You would have to select/prefetch the database fields/relations that the property uses under the hood:

```
qs = Place.objects.select_related('placebestpic')
```

Now, calling the property will not hit the db:

```
for p in qs:
    # do stuff with p.bestpicurl
```

Even though you are following a reverse relation here, you do not use `prefetch_related`. From the [`select_related` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

> You can also refer to the reverse direction of a OneToOneField in the list of fields passed to select_related — that is, you can traverse a OneToOneField back to the object on which the field is defined. Instead of specifying the field name, use the related_name for the field on the related object.